# Using RestSharp on iOS with 100% packet loss

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, restsharp

While testing an iOS app, I've used the developer settings to set an iPhone device to 100% Loss, and used a method to get some data from the server.

(The same scenario can also be simulated when connecting to a Wi-Fi without an an internet connection).

My assumption was that I won't get any data and will get a time-out.
The issue is that I'm getting a time-out for the first try, but if I try to execute the request again (using UIRefreshControl for example) the whole app gets stuck (getting the UI thread stuck) and later killed by the OS.

This is an example of the initial code I've used:

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = new Uri("some_url");
client.Timeout = 20000;

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
   //Doing some stuff
});
```

After some research I've modified the code and tried a few different approaches:

```
 private static async void getUserDataFromServer()
 {  
         var client = new RestClient();
         client.Timeout = 20000;
         var request = new RestRequest("http://www.google.com");
         var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

         var restResponse =
             await client.ExecuteAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
         Console.WriteLine(restResponse.Content);
 }
```

This also behaves the same.

Then I've tried explicitly to run it on a different thread:

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => getUserDataFromServer());
```

The last approach doesn't get the UI thread stuck, but if I run it more than once, the request doesn't return, even after the time out. 
Moreover at this point, if I make another request, without using a new thread, it will get the UI thread stuck.

Does anyone know how to solve it or have a better approach to this issue?
Please note that it only happens when there is a significant packet loss.

Comment: Well, have you tried `var restResponse = await client.ExecuteAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);`? It has nothing to do with RestSharp or iOS, just normal thread scheduling and async/await. There is a lot of information out there about async calls and UI threads.